# Threaded vs Thread

Tags: php, multithreading

I can't understand what is different between `Thread` and `Threaded`.
So I can understand that `Threaded` is a wrapper of pthread API.
And `Thread` extends it, and it gives more methods.
Yeah I know it, but I want to know.
Why did the developer make `Thread` though there is `Threaded`?
Where is the `Threaded` used?
What is the fundamental differences between those?

Comment: Just another library with a different implementation, like there is memcache and memcached.

Comment: No. 
https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/
this project implements both latter and former

Comment: Are you asking why he is extending a class?

Comment: @Thomas What is different? I mean when is Threaded used and when is Thread used?? What was the purpose of making the Thread class??

Comment: @ManDongI to extend the functionality of the base class.

Comment: @Thomas When is Threaded used instead of Thread? Hmm.. Is Thread a more comfortable version of Threaded?

Comment: @ManDongI the base class is probably used to extend other classes as well, this is called [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in object oriented programming.